# Postgres check if jsonb array not contains value returns empty result set

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, jsonb

Need to check if jsonb column contains and not contains value.
Jsonb field is a simple array:

```
ALTER TABLE task ADD COLUMN worker_ids jsonb;

UPDATE task SET worker_ids = '["1", "2"]' WHERE ...
```

Then trying to run queries to check either it contains or not contains concrete value:

Query which checks if jsonb contains value -  is  working fine and returns correct set of rows

```
 SELECT * FROM task WHERE worker_ids ? '1'
```

However when I add `NOT` to the where condition query returns simply nothing:

```
 SELECT * FROM task WHERE NOT worker_ids ? '1'
```

Am I getting something wrong ?

Comment: `worker_ids` array contains 1, so why are you expecting a result?

Comment: Are the other `worker_ids` fields NULL?

Comment: comparison against null gives null, not true or false, so `not null ? value` is not false and thus not returned

Comment: @eurotrash true :) I thought it is obvious because asking *why no rows returned for false* would be strange when you know they all are true. but yes, you are right - it's logical, not obvious

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparison.html

> Ordinary comparison operators yield null (signifying “unknown”), not
>   true or false, when either input is null. For example, 7 = NULL yields
>   null, as does 7 <> NULL. When this behavior is not suitable, use the
>   IS [ NOT ] DISTINCT FROM predicates:

something like:

```
SELECT * FROM task WHERE (worker_ids ? '1') is distinct from true
```

should work